# Python regex remove everything except strings from list

Tags: python, regex, list, replace

I have string:

```
bdv. mot. g. vns. kilm.
```

And knowing list of strings like

```
important_strings_lst=['bdv.', 'dktv.', 'mot. g.', 'vyr. g.']
```

I want to get `regex` selection like:

```
bdv. mot. g.
```

I joined list and tried: [idea from here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch05s04.html)

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b(?!bdv.|dktv.|mot. g.|vyr. g.)\w+', re.UNICODE)
regex.sub("", 'bdv. mot. g. vns. kilm.')
```

Got

```
'bdv. mot. . . .'
```

Changing places in regex with `\s` also didn't work out. How to do it?

I could use something like `[x for x in important_strings_lst if x in my_string]` but I need good performance as this will be used with million rows of pandas dataframe with [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` character has special meaning in regular expressions. You can use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to make a string "safe" for use in a regular expression.

```
>>> import re
... important_strings=['bdv.', 'dktv.', 'mot. g.', 'vyr. g.']
... regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(s) for s in important_strings))
... regex.findall('bdv. mot. g. vns. kilm.')
['bdv.', 'mot. g.']
```

Pandas has its own [`findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html#pandas.Series.str.findall) which should work like `re.findall`

Comment: @perreal,  your comment above is not clear, can your pls make it clear.

Comment: Pandas series indeed has `str.findall` method. And `re.escape` removes dots. What is left is list instead of string. But may I get out with this.

Comment: `.str.findall('|'.join(re.escape(s) for s in important_strings)).str.join(' ')`

Comment: You can benchmark to test if findall is faster than your original negative lookahead. I try to avoid using lookaround assertions in my regular expressions because they are often hard to read/understand and in some cases they can be very slow, if the regex engine is forced to do a lot of backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe split string

```
    bdv. mot. g. vns. kilm.
```

using your list and remove from oryginal string what left after spliting.